# How to retrieve value from nested struct

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, struct

I was creating the application to retrieve data from my Facebook page using FQL.
The fql query is:

```
select id, text, attachment.media.image.src FROM comment 
where post_id IN (SELECT post_id from stream where 
                  source_id = "mypageid" AND  actor_id = "mypageid" LIMIT 100)
```

I got the value for ID and TEXT by using this way:

```
public class MyComments
{
    public string id { get; set; } // this is comment id
    public string text { get; set; } // this is the comment
}

List<MyComments> q = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyComments>>
                                                     (results.data.ToString());
if (q.Count != 0)
{
    post_id = q[0].id.ToString();
    post_text = q[0].text.ToString();
}
```

But how to get the value for SRC, because it is struct in struct attachment > in struct media > in struct image > string src.

Is there a possible way to get value for string SRC? in c# code?

Please guys, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't played with FQL, but JSON is easy enough to deal with.

The first thing to do is to examine the JSON object returned by the FQL and see if it has nested structure objects in it or not.  Assuming that it does, you will need to create a class for each nested object.

Let's assume you have a JSON structure similar to this:

```
[{
    "id": "<comment id>",
    "text": "<comment text>",
    "attachment": {
        "media": {
            "image": {
                src: "<image source string>"
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    ...
}]
```

In order to unpack that into a C# class you'll need a class for each level: attachment -> media -> image:

```
public class MyComments
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public Attachment attachment { get; set; }

    public class Attachment
    {
        public Media media { get; set; }
    }

    public class Media 
    {
        public Image image { get; set; }
    }

    public class Image 
    {
        public string src { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Of course if you have a use for those classes outside of the single response you can un-nest them and add any other fields you might use.  I find it simpler to use this way, since everything is encapsulated within the result record class.

Once you've deserialized the response from FQL you should be able to access the `src` item with (in your code above):

```
post_src = q[0].attachment.media.image.src;
```

Just be careful that the JSON matches the structure you've laid out for it, or you will get some deserialization errors.  Watch for arrays especially - they can mess you up unless you're ready for them.

---

Edit: [removed section on Arrays since it doesn't fit your actual use-case]

---

Here's a set of classes that will deserialize the JSON you posted on PasteBin:

```
public class MyComments
{
    public string post_id;
    public string message;
    public Attachment attachment;


    public class Attachment
    {
        public Media[] media;
    }

    public class Media
    {
        public string href;
        public string alt;
        public string type;
        public string src;
        public Photo photo;
    }

    public class Photo
    {
        public string aid;
        public string pid;
        public string fbid;
        public string owner;
        public int index;
        public int width;
        public int height;
        public Image[] images;
    }

    public class Image
    {
        public string src;
        public int width;
        public int height;
    }
}
```

Tested against the posted JSON:

```
MyComments comment = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyComments>(jsrc);
Console.WriteLine("Source: {0}", comment.attachment.media[0].photo.images[0].src);
```

Output:

```
Source: https://fbcdn-sphotos-a-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfa1/t1.0-9/s720x720/10288743_852243528123890_8104585654908358176_n.jpg
```

Just be aware that the arrays can be empty, so the above could fail with `IndexOutOfRangeException`.  Always test the `Length` of your arrays before indexing them.

I'd write some code in the `MyComments.Photo` class to find the image that matches your criteria - largest dimensions, for instance.  Something like this:

```
public Image LargestImage()
{
    return images.OrderByDescending(i => i.width).ThenByDescending(i => i.height).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Then you can always get the largest image, regardless of what order the images are supplied in, or `null` if the image list is empty:

```
var img = comment.attachment.media[0].photo.LargestImage();
if (img != null)
    Console.WriteLine("Source: {0}", img.src);
```

For a list of the sources of the largest image for all media attached to the comment:

```
var q = 
    (
        from m in comment.attachment.media
        let img = m.photo.LargestImage()
        where img != null
        select img.src
    ).ToList();
```

Or without the `LargestImage` method:

```
var q = 
    (
        from m in comment.attachment.media
        let img = m.photo.images
            .OrderByDescending(i => i.width)
            .ThenByDescending(i => i.height)
            .FirstOrDefault()
        where img != null
        select img.src
    ).ToList();
```

Works even if no `images` entries could be parsed out of the JSON for whatever reason.

Comment: mr. Corey, did u know how to get the string value when in the middle of struct had array type. Example:
struct Attachment, struct Media, array Photo, struct Image, string src

how to get src value?

Comment: Updated.  If you like, paste a sanitized version of the JSON string over at [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com) and I'll have a look at the true structure.

Comment: corey, i had already put the jason at http://pastebin.com/QwW6DuMa . help me please how to get the src value